# Using vagrant and chef to setup a Windows VM in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, virtualbox, chef, vagrant

I'm running Ubuntu and I want to setup a VM in Virtualbox via Vagrant and Chef.  I think what I'm missing is a .box for the Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 trial I have.

Does anyone know where I could find a .box?  If not, how would I go about building a Vagrant .box for Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently had to build a Vagrant .box for Windows Server 2008 R2 using Chef provisioning.  I blogged about my experiences [here](http://jongalentine.com/2012/12/22/creating-vagrant-base-boxes-with-veewee/).  As Henk mentioned, you'll first need to create the basebox using a [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) template.  I recommend using the windows-2008R2-serverstandard-amd64-winrm template.

Comment: Right. But instead of veewee, I would use Packer (http://www.packer.io/) these days.

Answer (score 4):

Distributing a .box with Windows would be illegal. Public / free boxes however can be found on the site [Vagrantbox.es](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)

You could try and build your own box with [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee). The author of veewee shows in this video how he built a Windows7 box: [veewee does windows7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spzfvaO17yc), so Windows Server 2k8 *might* be possible too, since there are templates available from within veewee:

```
# veewee templates
... snip ...
vagrant basebox define '<boxname>' 'windows-2008R1-serverstandard-amd64'
vagrant basebox define '<boxname>' 'windows-2008R2-amd64'
vagrant basebox define '<boxname>' 'windows-2008R2-serverstandard-amd64'
```

You'll also need a W2k8 DVD or ISO-image of course.

Comment: Would (re)distributing a box based on an evaluation version (such as the ones offered by Microsoft at [Modern.IE](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)) also be illegal?

Answer (score 0):

[In this git repository](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/tree/master/templates) you find many vagrant configs and documentation. there some windows machines, too. i didn't test these, yet - but i was told they are working (and the linux configs are working for sure). if you try these it would be great if you could give a little feedback. i may need them in the future, too ;)